# Positive addition operations producing a negative number

Tags: c#, int32

I am writing a script to take a series of number from a csv file and total them.

I have extracted the values from the csv into a `List<string>` and am looping over that to add them together.
The numbers are millisecond representations of each minute in the day, so generally starting at `0` and incrementing by `6000`.

For some reason though, the final numbers appear to be negative.
I am checking at the end of the addition operations and the final count is less than `1`.

I tried printing the numbers to the console and they are correct, I guess something wrong somewhere else?

`Screenshot of sample out`

[image]

Thanks in advance.

```
var totalSeconds = 0;
var minutesCounted = 0;
var unzippedFolder = Compression.UnzipToFolder(zipPath);
var listOfSeconds = ReadCsvIndex(unzippedFolder[0], ",", 0, true);

foreach (var second in listOfSeconds)
{
   // Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(second)); // Prints correct numbers
   totalSeconds += Int32.Parse(second);
   minutesCounted++;
   Console.WriteLine(minutesCounted + totalSeconds);
}

Console.WriteLine(security + totalSeconds);
Console.WriteLine(minutesCounted);
File.Delete(unzippedFolder[0]);

if (totalSeconds > 1)
{
  Console.WriteLine(true);
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine(false); // This is returning false
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `long` value instead of the default `int` for that `totalSeconds`.
The value apparently goes above [Int32.MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx), so the value wraps around to negative that.

A `long` has a much higher max value, so you will not get this overflow effect (at least, not as soon)